# Jquery Hide/show destroy Chosen Plugin CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#b").hide();
    $(".chosen").chosen();

    $("#a").click(function(){$("#b").show();});
});
</script>

<p id="a">aaaa</p>

<div id="b">
<select class="chosen">
<option>Classification</option>
<option>aaaa</option>
<option>bbb</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I have select drop down list use Chosen Plugin. However when I try to hide the form and use click to show the form, the chosen css layout will get destroyed.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cZV6G/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work.  If you're going to attach a fiddle to your question, please make sure it is working before doing so.

Comment: how come, i just check, there is no problem

Comment: 500 Server error when loading resources from your website.

Comment: i have no idea, its ok from my side

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can try to set `visibility` of element.

For resolving this you can use `visibility:hidden` instead of `.hide()` and for showing the drop-down use `visibility:visible` instead of `.show()`.

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#b").css('visibility','hidden');
    $(".chosen").chosen();
    $("#a").click(function(){$("#b").css('visibility','visible');});
});
```

[Try is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZV6G/1/)

**Update: Resolve Visibility Problem**

There is no problem with jquery `.hide()`. The real problem is, you hide element before applying the `.chosen()`. But if you try hide element after applying the `.chosen()`, then it works correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".chosen").chosen();
    $("#b").hide();
    $("#a").click(function(){$("#b").show();});
});
```

[Try with .hide()](http://jsfiddle.net/cZV6G/2/)

Comment: it works! thx a lot!, do u know how to change chosen default font?
i have try to change chosen.css font-family:Arial; but its not working

Comment: but you can try to make changes into plugin css class(chosen.css). There is a ".chosen-container" class where you can try to put your font style. I hope this will help you to achieve your task

Comment: i still have 1 problem, if i use visibility, my layout will have big gap, because the element still there

Comment: visibility is just make element not see, but still there, therefor it still have width height, it will have a empty space between :(

Comment: Yes, you are right. visibility:hidden only hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout. But there many way exist if you want, element not take space. You can set height:0 of the element, and set actual height when element is visible.

Comment: There is no problem hiding the element before initializing the chosen element. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to this post but I want to share my experience in this case.

There is no problem hiding the element before initializing the chosen element.

What I do is apply a `width` properties when you initialize the chosen element.

```js
$("#yourSelect").chosen({ width: "100%" })
```

Ref.[Doc](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#options)    The width of the Chosen select box. By default, Chosen attempts to match the width of the select box you are replacing. If your select is hidden when Chosen is instantiated, you must specify a width or the select will show up with a width of 0.

Example below:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //select element is initialised when it is hidden.
    $("#select1").chosen({ width: "100%" });
    
    $("#showBtn").on("click",function(){
      $("#wrapper").removeClass("hidden");
    })
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hidden" id="wrapper">
  <select id="select1">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button id="showBtn">Show the select element</button>
```